# java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed Client

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, keystore, truststore

I am trying to link my Java Message Service (JMS) Apache Qpid 0.11.1 client to a broker server(QPID JMS Broker 6.1.4) , using SSL. I am getting "Signature check failed" error.

Keystore/truststore/certificates have been done both ways and uploaded to client/server:

```
    -- CREATE KEYSTORE in current directory for client
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 365 -sigalg SHA256withRSA -alias mdbbu -keystore MDBBU.jks -storepass MDBBUPWD -keypass MDBBUPWD -dname CN=MDBBU

-- EXPORT CERTIFICATE FOR UPLOAD
keytool -export -rfc -alias mdbbu -file MDBBU.cer -keystore MDBBU.jks

-- CREATE KEYSTORE in current directory for Server
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 365 -sigalg SHA256withRSA -alias qpid -keystore QPID.jks -storepass QPIDPWD -keypass QPIDPWD -dname CN=QPID

-- EXPORT CERTIFICATE FOR UPLOAD
keytool -export -rfc -alias qpid -file QPID.cer -keystore QPID.jks

-- CREATE TRUSTSTORE FOR CLIENT
keytool -import -file QPID.cer -alias qpid -keystore MDBBUTRUSTSTORE

-- CREATE TRUSTSTORE FOR SERVER
keytool -import -file MDBBU.cer -alias mdbbu -keystore QPIDTRUSTSTORE

-- ADD QPID certificate to Java CACERT 
keytool -import -alias QPID -keystore ../../etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/java/cacerts -file QPID.cer -storepass changeit
```

I have also specified the SSL to:

`Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=[...]qpid.conf/keystore/MDBBUTRUSTSTORE
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit`

The error I am getting is the following (from SSL debug):

```
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1511206004 bytes = { 69, 198, 205, 186, 121, 194, 64, 133, 34, 237, 39, 73, 145, 23, 174, 30, 20, 28, 252, 52, 167, 74, 5, 166, 61, 6, 127, 242 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 207
0000: 01 00 00 CB 03 03 5A 13   2C 74 45 C6 CD BA 79 C2  ......Z.,tE...y.

[some more date of same type]
...
[some more date of same type]

00C0: 03 04 01 03 03 03 01 02   03 02 01 02 02 01 01     ...............
nioEventLoopGroup-15-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 207
[Raw write]: length = 212
0000: 16 03 03 00 CF 01 00 00   CB 03 03 5A 13 2C 74 45  ...........Z.,tE

[some more date of same type]
...
[some more date of same type]

00C0: 05 03 05 01 04 03 04 01   03 03 03 01 02 03 02 01  ................
00D0: 02 02 01 01                                        ....
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 16 03 03 04 88                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 1160
0000: 02 00 00 4D 03 03 5A 13   2C 74 AC 9B 2D F9 FA 59  ...M..Z.,t..-..Y
0010: BB C7 45 A0 9F ED B5 3F   7D 05 D4 83 D3 36 FE 4C  ..E....?.....6.L
0020: F0 B6 CB 87 86 F9 20 5A   13 2C 74 B9 A3 88 97 6E  ...... Z.,t....n

[some more date of same type]
.....
[some more date of same type]

nioEventLoopGroup-15-1, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 1160
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1511206004 bytes = { 172, 155, 45, 249, 250, 89, 187, 199, 69, 160, 159, 237, 181, 63, 125, 5, 212, 131, 211, 54, 254, 76, 240, 182, 203, 135, 134, 249 }
Session ID:  {90, 19, 44, 116, 185, 163, 136, 151, 110, 50, 63, 177, 133, 218, 234, 231, 137, 97, 39, 29, 23, 216, 182, 65, 42, 165, 18, 173, 201, 44, 18, 160}
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-13, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
** TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 81
0000: 02 00 00 4D 03 03 5A 13   2C 74 AC 9B 2D F9 FA 59  ...M..Z.,t..-..Y
0010: BB C7 45 A0 9F ED B5 3F   7D 05 D4 83 D3 36 FE 4C  ..E....?.....6.L
0020: F0 B6 CB 87 86 F9 20 5A   13 2C 74 B9 A3 88 97 6E  ...... Z.,t....n
0030: 32 3F B1 85 DA EA E7 89   61 27 1D 17 D8 B6 41 2A  2?......a'....A*
0040: A5 12 AD C9 2C 12 A0 C0   27 00 00 05 FF 01 00 01  ....,...'.......
0050: 00                                                 .
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=Qpid
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 17838898949194272763895904858029226742114411817633075440405824167496480878348219699071565266078743537513078586324053239358525649068739492259769179774376050243276494306041626152510770477107599166026312713480244773516248270063435812230147814274925586413575881169761140524134516039035163897980173923048645022578386644259910551912486834492258399033030846089211424992068118178712060197808521227471448918782773290447418660595134969271364486398667411290097082667956825083588193700666666652215335564892445838118728747305105358975738471545453493561867895848599405458487626990687846267295266248036139124227410954876752876840907
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Thu Nov 16 18:25:12 CET 2017,
               To: Fri Nov 16 18:25:12 CET 2018]
  Issuer: CN=Qpid
  SerialNumber: [    2c24541a]

Certificate Extensions: 1
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: localhost
  DNSName: <Instance name>.sys.net
  IPAddress: some IP 
  IPAddress: some IP 
  IPAddress: some IP 
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:

  [...] Signature stuff [....]

]
***
nioEventLoopGroup-15-1, fatal error: 46: General SSLEngine problem
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
%% Invalidated:  [Session-13, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
nioEventLoopGroup-15-1, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
nioEventLoopGroup-15-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
nioEventLoopGroup-15-1, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
nioEventLoopGroup-15-1, called closeOutbound()
nioEventLoopGroup-15-1, closeOutboundInternal()
nioEventLoopGroup-15-1, called closeInbound()
nioEventLoopGroup-15-1, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
nioEventLoopGroup-15-1, called closeOutbound()
nioEventLoopGroup-15-1, closeOutboundInternal()
nioEventLoopGroup-15-1, called closeInbound()
nioEventLoopGroup-15-1, closeInboundInternal()
```

I must be missing something, however, the error:

```
nioEventLoopGroup-15-1, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
```

seems a bit strange to me. I am not sure if my certificates are setup wrongly or there is something else. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

P.S. Sorry if the question doesn't seem aligned to Stackoverflow guidelines but it's my first post. : - )

Comment: Why are your commands to create the truststore for client and server the same? They shouldn't be.

Comment: Sorry, probably didn't copy correctly... I have updated the question.

Comment: The only thing that seems like it might be wrong in my head is the fact that I have only specified a Common Name (CN) and not Location, Organization name, etc. but this info is probably not used for verification.

Comment: The cert received from the server (displayed by JSSE) has a differently-cased CN than the command you say you used, and it has SAN which the command you say you used doesn't, and the signature failure strongly suggests it has a different key -- in short it is not at all the same cert. Check you are connecting to the correct server and the server is using the correct keystore.